# Highcharts pie with strokes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I'm trying to generate a pie chart as in the following link:
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic

However, I didn't find a way to display the strokes (if that is how it is called)
[image]

Can someone kindly explain how I should do that?
I use 4.2.6 version

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you provide your code?

This "strokes" are there out of the box so if you don't see them you probably have some settings that overrides them.
Basically if they're shown or not is based on distance. By default they are there.
But if you set labels distance to 0 or lower (negative value) they will be gone.

I.E. http://jsfiddle.net/Lsfjgtzo/2/

```
distance: -10,
```

(with strokes) http://jsfiddle.net/temd5p9w/1/

```
distance: 30,
```

Comment: Thank you Pawel! I don't know why, but I had negative distance. It solved the problem. Have a great day.